# Customize object creation over JAXB deserialization

Tags: java, jaxb

I have the class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ClassFqn", propOrder = { <some properties> })
public class ClassFqn
{       
   //... Here should be fields, constructor and logic
}
```

Objects are immutable and I use cached objects pool factory instead of direct creation.

Can I use this pool factory when I do JAXB deserialization for these objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways that you could support this use case.

### Option #1 - Use `@XmlType` to specify Factory Class & Method

You can use the `@XmlType` annotation to specify a factory class and method:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(
    name = "ClassFqn", 
    propOrder = { <some properties> }
    factoryClass=ClassFqnFactory.class,
    factoryMethod="createClassFqn")
public class ClassFqn
{       
   //... Here should be fields, constructor and logic
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/jaxb-and-factory-methods.html

### Option #2 - Use an `XmlAdapter`

An `XmlAdapter` can also be leveraged.  Essentially you read the data into a temporary object and then implement the `XmlAdapter` to use your own mechanisms to create the final object.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-immutable-objects.html